# Searching across aggregates in DDD

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, code-first

I have the following scenario in DDD.

```
public class Document
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string DocumentCode {get;set;}
public int BuyerId {get;set;}
}

public class Buyer
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And now I want to search all documents that contain buyer with a name "John".

Since Buyer is a different aggregate, I am thinking of these scenarios

**Create new aggregate**

```
public class DocumentSearch
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string DocumentCode {get;set;}
public int BuyerId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

The "problem" here is that this aggregate need to listen to any Buyer changes and apply changes locally.

**Keep everything as it is.**

And on db level create a view that would act as a new aggregate. Problem here is that it breaks every DDD principle and the app is not really persistence ignorant

**Do search and join on app level**

Basically do a search on Document, do a search on Buyer and join it at application level. I believe this would require more time and power, since both sets would be initially larger then they should actually be in merged search?

What would be a way to go in order to follow DDD principles? CQRS is the ultimate solution, but I am looking for a transient solution on the way to CQRS

Comment: Not 100% acclimated to DDD just yet, but it would seem that your class `DocumentSearch` could actually be one of the (single) _results_ of a search.  I would think you might want to have a search request class, i.e.  `class DocumentSearchRequest { public string NameToSearch { get; set; } }`.  At the application level, do your "search and join on app level" using the request class (small set) and return a collection of the result class.
Forgive any DDD insolence I may have (at this point) :-)

Comment: According to Greg Young, DDD can't be done without CQRS. If you don't use CQRS you should expect many problems which doesn't have any clean solution like this one.

Answer (score 0):

> Asking a question shouldn't change the answer.

Since a search doesn't change the answer, you don't normally need a domain model or domain entities to support it.

The usual solutions are to either (a) query your data model directly or (b) create a "read model" to support the queries.

(a) is exactly what it says on the tin.  If you are storing data in an RDBMS, then just query -> dto? -> response.

Read models are often used where query support isn't viable.  A read model is effectively a cached DTO - you build a representation of the set as things change.  Most often, you'll see this done asynchronously -- queries are run against the "latest" representation, and a background workflow is run to propagate changes to that representation.